# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to assign a png file to all the products in my database, Spring boot doesn't recognize either the path or the file

I've assigned the value "unknown.png" to the photoName attribute of every Product, the filename is the same as this value and it is indeed a PNG file, I tried to change the format of the path, and I tried to add a ToString() to the path, but I get the same exception when I open localhost:8000/photoProduct/1 when it should display the image instead

The RestController is as follows:

```
@RestController
public class CatalogueRestController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    
     @GetMapping(path="/photoProduct/{id}",produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
        public byte[] getPhoto(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws Exception{
            Product p=productRepository.findById(id).get();
            return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/info1/ecom/products/unknown.png"));
        }
    
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does the file exist? Is the user called `PC` where this code runs?

Comment: Yes it does exist

Comment: What does `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));` print when the method is called?

Comment: it prints C:\Users\PC

Comment: Okay. If you check with Windows Explorer, you can see `C:\Users\PC\Desktop` and its contents, right?

Comment: yes i get a list of the files in my desktop

Comment: Then it must be a typo in the path or some weird Windows accessibility problem along the path. Put `unknown.png` directly onto the desktop, reference it in `get` and see if that works.

Comment: Nope, Still the same error message when I tried this:  "Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Comment: I'd suggest keep moving `unknown.png` up the parent directories one by one till `C:\\` and see if any of that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with `\\\` instead of `/` and it works.

```java
@GetMapping(path="/photoProduct/{id}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
public byte[] getPhoto(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws IOException {
    Product p = productRepository.findById(id).get();
    return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\ecom\\products\\"+p.getPhotoName()));
}
```